# Marker won't follow orientation of a cardinal-curved path in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a path with a cardinal spline in d3 and a triangle as a marker-end. However it seems that the marker does not follow the path's orientation if the spline is cardinal.

Here's an example:

```js
var svg = d3.selectAll('svg.one');
var svg2 = d3.selectAll('svg.two');
var svg3 = d3.selectAll('svg.three')

var coords = [[20, 30], [140, 60], [180, 120]]

svg.append('svg:defs')
  .append('svg:marker')
  .attr('id', 'triangle_marker')
  .attr('markerHeight', 5)
  .attr('markerWidth', 5)
  .attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
  .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .attr('refX', 0)
  .attr('refY', 0)
  .attr('viewBox', '-5 -5 10 10')
  .append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', 'M 0,0 m -5,-5 L 5,0 L -5,5 Z')
  .attr('fill', '#00c0ff');

svg.append('path')
.attr('d', d3.line()(coords))
.style('fill', 'none')
.style('stroke-width', '3.5px')
.style('stroke', '#000')
.attr('marker-end', 'url(#triangle_marker)');

svg2.append('path')
.attr('d', d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis)(coords))
.style('fill', 'none')
.style('stroke-width', '3.5px')
.style('stroke', '#000')
.attr('marker-end', 'url(#triangle_marker)')

svg3.append('path')
.attr('d', d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal)(coords))
.style('fill', 'none')
.style('stroke-width', '3.5px')
.style('stroke', '#000')
.attr('marker-end', 'url(#triangle_marker)')
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Normal Line</h2>
    <svg class="one" height="300" width="300"></svg>
    <h2>Basis Line</h2>
    <svg class="two" height="300" width="300"></svg>
    <h2>Cardinal Line</h2>
    <svg class="three" height="300" width="300"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the marker in the cardinal path doesn't follow its orientation. D3 versions prior to v4 doesn't have this problem.

Could anyone guide me in solving this problem? Or is it just impossible?

Comment: Might actually be a bug in chrome.  Works in both Edge and IE11.  The difference from from d3 version 3 to version 4, is it looks like M Bostock switched from quadratic curves to bezier ones.

Comment: And here's the [chrome bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450368)